# Same action on multiple variables and make into a data frame in the end

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, for-loop, lapply

I am doing the same action on multiple variables. And final goal is to make them into a data frame. I am wondering if there is an easy way instead of repeating to write the same action code. I am thinking about "lappy", "loop"("for loop", "repeat loop")

Thanks for the help!

```css
o<-df$samples

a<-o[[1]]      
b<-o[[2]] 
c<-o[[3]]
d<-o[[4]]
.
.
.
z<-o[[26]]

a <- a[order(a[,2]),]
a <- paste(a[,1],a[,2],sep="</td> <td>")
a <- paste("<tr><td>",a, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
a <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>",a,"</td></tr></table>" )


b <- b[order(b[,2]),]
b <- paste(b[,1],b[,2],sep="</td> <td>")
b <- paste("<tr><td>",b, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
b <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>",b,"</td></tr></table>" )

c <- c[order(c[,2]),]
c <- paste(c[,1],a[,2],sep="</td> <td>")
c <- paste("<tr><td>",c, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
c <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>",c,"</td></tr></table>" )

d <- d[order(d[,2]),]
d <- paste(d[,1],[,2],sep="</td> <td>")
d <- paste("<tr><td>",d, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
d <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>",d,"</td></tr></table>" )
.
.
.
.
z <- z[order(z[,2]),]
z <- paste(z[,1],[,2],sep="</td> <td>")
z <- paste("<tr><td>",z, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
z <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>",z,"</td></tr></table>" )

DF <- data.frame(a,b,c,d,........,z)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: @Sotos Could you help me with this question?

Comment: It has been answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the OP mentioned the same task is repeated, then create a function and apply over the `list`

```
out <- data.frame(lapply(o, f1))
```

where

```
f1 <- function(x) {   
     x[order(x[,2]),]
     x <- paste(x[,1], x[,2], sep="</td> <td>")
     x<- paste("<tr><td>", x, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
     x <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4";>", 
           x, "</td></tr></table>" )
     x
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! When I ran the function(x) it shows the error message that "unexpected numeric constant in:
 x<- paste("<tr><td>", x, collapse = "</td></tr>")   
  x <- paste0("<table border='1px'; style='width:100%'; cellpadding="4"

Comment: Also, I don't need to do any action on a<-o[[1]]      
b<-o[[2]] 
c<-o[[3]]
d<-o[[4]]
.
.
.
z<-o[[26]] ?

Comment: @Rbeginnnnnner No, you don't need to create multiple variables

Comment: @Rbeginnnnnner. I don't find any issue in the code as it is a translation of your code

Comment: @Rbeginnnnnner its your css problem double inverted coma is clashing with outer comas. convert all your double inverted coma to single as your css is wrapped inside double inverted coma

Comment: @akrun It is my mistake. Thanks for your kindly help!

Comment: @geekzeus I fix it. Thanks!